# Match EOL character?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the commands from a string of RTTTL commands like this:

```
 2a4, 2e, 2d#, 2b4, 2a4, 2c, 2d, 2a#4, 2e., e, 1f4, 1a4, 1d#, 2e., d, 2c., b4, 1a4, 1p, 2a4, 2e, 2d#, 2b4, 2a4, 2c, 2d, 2a#4, 2e., e, 1f4, 1a4, 1d#, 2e., d, 2c., b4, 1a4
```

The regex I'm using is `(\S+),|$` with global and multiline on, as I read that `$` matches EOL when multiline mode is on, however this does not happen, and thus I cannot capture the last command `1a4`, which ends the line. All the other commands are captured from the group.

What's the regex I should be using to capture the last command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a lookahead or non-capturing group like below. And get the string you want from group index 1.

```
(\S+)(?:,|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xJ4nN9/2)

OR

```
(\S+)(?=,|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xJ4nN9/1)

You don't need to have a capturing group also when using lookahead.

```
\S+(?=,|$)
```

`(?=,|$)` Positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by a `,` or end of the line anchor. `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

Comment: Aha! That works! Thanks, I'm pretty new to regex. I'll accept as answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

**another solution**

```
$a = " 2a4, 2e, 2d#, 2b4, 2a4, 2c, 2d, 2a#4, 2e., e, 1f4, 1a4, 1d#, 2e., d, 2c., b4, 1a4, 1p, 2a4, 2e, 2d#, 2b4, 2a4, 2c, 2d, 2a#4, 2e., e, 1f4, 1a4, 1d#, 2e., d, 2c., b4, 1a4"; 
$r=explode(",",preg_replace("/\\s+/","",$a));
var_dump($r);
```

**output:**

```
array (size=37)
  0 => string '2a4' (length=3)
  1 => string '2e' (length=2)
  2 => string '2d#' (length=3)
  3 => string '2b4' (length=3)
  4 => string '2a4' (length=3)
  5 => string '2c' (length=2)
  6 => string '2d' (length=2)
  7 => string '2a#4' (length=4)
  8 => string '2e.' (length=3)
  9 => string 'e' (length=1)
  10 => string '1f4' (length=3)
  11 => string '1a4' (length=3)
  12 => string '1d#' (length=3)
  13 => string '2e.' (length=3)
  14 => string 'd' (length=1)
  15 => string '2c.' (length=3)
  16 => string 'b4' (length=2)
  17 => string '1a4' (length=3)
  18 => string '1p' (length=2)
  19 => string '2a4' (length=3)
  20 => string '2e' (length=2)
  21 => string '2d#' (length=3)
  22 => string '2b4' (length=3)
  23 => string '2a4' (length=3)
  24 => string '2c' (length=2)
  25 => string '2d' (length=2)
  26 => string '2a#4' (length=4)
  27 => string '2e.' (length=3)
  28 => string 'e' (length=1)
  29 => string '1f4' (length=3)
  30 => string '1a4' (length=3)
  31 => string '1d#' (length=3)
  32 => string '2e.' (length=3)
  33 => string 'd' (length=1)
  34 => string '2c.' (length=3)
  35 => string 'b4' (length=2)
  36 => string '1a4' (length=3)
```